# Pynput: Leftclick does not work on textfields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I wanted to write a script that moves the mouse on a textfield, leftklicks to activate writing and write some text into it. However for some reason the mouseclick does not work on the textfield but it workes on everything else.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()

def singleklick():
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(round(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0), 10))

def typeText(text):
    keyboard.type(text.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(round(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0), 10))

def search(item):
    jumpToCoordinate(coordinates.get('search'))
    singleklick()
    time.sleep(round(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0), 10))
    typeText(item)
```

item is a string

jumpToCoordinate is my function to move the mouse to the given coordinate

What happens is that the cursor moves perfectly on the textfield but it does not recognize the performed mouseklick and I absolutly don't get why because the mouseclick works perfectly on everything else (buttons and so on)

Comment: I tried your code on mac, `singleklick()` and `typeText()` work fine on the browser, however, it required me to add a security exception for Terminal to control the computer for the first time which I added. Can you provide a bit more context about your OS and where you are trying click. Is it within a browser or any desktop application?

Comment: It's a desktop application running on windows. I solved the problem by using `mouse.press(Button.left)
time.sleep(round(random.uniform(0.5, 1.0), 10))
mouse.release(Button.left)` I gues the click was performed too fast for the application?